# Sitecore: Create component and insert into placeholder on page creation

Tags: sitecore

We have developed a Sitecore site for a client who will primarily be using Page Editor. We've built page type layouts and then componentized everything else, including sub-layouts of content. This allows them the most flexibility when building pages.

So, an author goes to a page selects the main content area (Placeholder) of the page and inserts basic building block components that we've created. These include Rich Text box, page promos, etc. they can use these to build pretty rich pages with lengthy content.

All page components have the same Datasource Location, which is a "Page Components" folder that's setup as an item bucket.

This is all working well so far.

Now, I'm trying to make it so when a page is created a specific component is created, inserted into to our "Page Components" bucket and placed in a specific placeholder on the page.

I've been trying to build a Branch Template to accomplish this, but I don't see how to specify that the new component should be stored in our bucket location, instead of directly underneath the Page item. Also, how to make the component show up in the placeholder that I want on the page.

Is this possible? Thanks in advance for you help!

Comment: I haven't used them much, but you might have more luck with a command template rather than a branch template - even then it might be a struggle to achieve what you want.

Comment: As Martin says, take a look at this article: http://pageditor.wordpress.com/2014/11/21/datasource-for-components-standard-values-question-from-multi-site-best-practices-presentation/

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use a command template for this, since you are desiring to programmatically bypass Sitecore's standard layout configurations and branch template creation.

On your page template standard values, you will want to add the sublayout to the  presentation details so you can hook the datasource in programmatically after creation.

The fundamental flow in the command will be as follows:

1. Create the desired page item
2. Create the desired component datasource in the bucket location
3. Search the layout definition of the created page item to find the appropriate sublayout to bind to.
4. Alter the datasource on the sublayout to bind to the datasource you created.

As @jammykam mentioned, there is a [recent blog post now available](http://pageditor.wordpress.com/2014/11/21/datasource-for-components-standard-values-question-from-multi-site-best-practices-presentation/).